# How to code great circle distances into glmmtmb mixed effect model?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, glmmtmb

I am trying to run a mixed effect model using the 'glmmtmb' package with a spatial covariance structure that accounts for distances between points on a sphere. I have dug into the source code and identified where I think they calculate the Euclidean distances for the spatial covariance structure. I know euclidean distances are used based on this website:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html

By bringing up the source code:

```
trace(getReStruc, edit = T)
```

Line 44 is where they use the `dist(coords)` for that distance matrix.

I want to change that = code so that it calculates great circle distances instead of Euclidean ones. However, functions such as distHaversine() from the 'geosphere' packages require 4 arguments (lat of x1, long of x1, lat of x2, long of x2) so I can't just plug in:

```
geosphere::distHaversine(coords)
```

Does anyone have a work around for doing this? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: This is probably going to require significant hacking.  You might want to bring this up as an issue at https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues ...

Comment: @BenBolker will do!